# How to force VolumeParameter<T>()

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, urp

I have a little problem with VolumeParameter<>, the bottom line is, I want to add a new field in the inspector and drag any object into this field,
I did so:

```
  public VolumeParameter<Transform> test = new ();
```

[image]
but can't drag it to this field, also cannot be selected in this window:
[image]

Is there a workaround for VolumeParameter?

PS: Making my effect for URP.

I also tried to do it through:

```
    public ObjectParameter<Transform> test = new(null);
```

but nothing happened, constant errors appear.

Comment: Unity in the past didn't support serialization of generics ... so afaik worst case would be to have a non-generic wrapper and do `[Serializable] public class TransformParameter : VolumeParameter<Transform> { }` and then `public TransformParameter test;` and see if that does it

Comment: What objects are you trying to drag in, and will it always be that object or do you need it to be able to accept any kind of objects? Also, what errors are you getting when using `ObjectParameter<>`

Comment: @derHug, Unfortunately, this does not work either, the effect is the same.

Comment: @CodyC, As they say in the documentation, I must specify some other Transform: https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.core@11.0/api/UnityEngine.Rendering.ObjectParameter-1.html

  public ObjectParameter<Transform> test = new ObjectParameter<Transform>(?);

Comment: having `null` as default value should be fine actually ... if it is serialized you don't even need to initialize the field at all .. this will be done by the serializer

Comment: ^this. `public ObjectParameter<Transform> test = new ObjectParameter<Transform>(null)` - did you actually try it and get any errors though like you said?

Comment: @КодиС, Writes this:
 NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

But I can't just take and assign or create a new one Transform

public Transform t;
 public ObjectParameter<Transform> test = new ObjectParameter<Transform>(t);

or

 public ObjectParameter<Transform> test1 = new ObjectParameter<Transform>(new Transform());

Comment: Hmmm, actually, this is might be because it's expecting a non-null value, but received null instead. You could try changing your code to handle null values by changing the type of the parameter to nullable, which allows for null values to be assigned. By using this: public ObjectParameter<Transform?> test = new ObjectParameter<Transform?>() This would allow test to be assigned null values, but ensure that any non-null values passed to it are of type Transform!